# Dirac $\delta(g(x))$ with complex roots $x_i$

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

Hey we all know about this infamous Wikipedia page [Dirac-delta composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function)
related to the Dirac-$\delta$ in composition with a function $g(x)$.

But I wonder if the roots of $g(x) = 0$ happens to be of the form $r+\mathrm{i}s$ with $r,s\in\mathbf{R}$; is $\int_{\Omega} f(x)\delta(g(x)) \mathrm{d}x =^?0$, here $\Omega$ is an integration path **on** the real line.

I suspect it should be zero since we never encounter them, but I would like to hear your arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are concerned that something like the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) might have an effect on such an integral. The Residue Theorem only holds for functions meromorphic on the domain inside the path of integration, and $\delta\circ g=0$ is not. $delta$ is zero everywhere but where its argument is $0$. Therefore, if the roots of $g$ are not real, then $\delta\circ g=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

In the terms of distributions, the support of $\delta\circ g$ is the set of zeros (the roots) of $g$, therefore, if $\Omega\cap\{z:g(z)=0\}=\{\}$, then
$$
\int_\Omega f(x)\,\delta\circ g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the function $g(x)$ has no roots in the domain of Integration, the result should always be zero. This has nothing to do with composition but rather with the properties of the delta function - namely that it's equal to zero everywhere except for $\delta(0)$.